# Pattern match in PHP - copy only word with extension .inp

Tags: php, regex

I want to display the string just before the .inp and I wrote a php script for checking whether string contain .inp extension or not.
and it will print the whole line..... that contains .inp extension
But I need to print a word that containing .inp extension

For an example, I have a line
"new file name as xrs.inp is found on your machine"
I need to print only xrs.inp
Script I wrote is given below

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['ip10'])) {
    $connection = ssh2_connect($ip10, 22);
    ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');
    $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'ps -efa | grep g09 ');
    stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
    $output = stream_get_contents($stream);
    $array = explode(" ", $output);
    $checks = array('.inp');
    foreach ($checks as $check) {
        $place = strpos($output, $check);
        if (!empty($place)) {
            echo '.inp file is running on this server' . "<br>";
            exit;
        } else {
            echo "not present any .inp file" . "<br>";
        }
    }
    fclose($errorStream);
    fclose($stream);
}
?>
```

Please help me to print the name followed by .inp extension

Comment: What if the filename has a space?

Comment: How's this related to [tag:ssh]?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl he is getting the string from an ssh connection, but it isnt related to the problem, indead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note this will only work if your file name has no space in between. I have slightly modified your solution.

Try this

```
$output="new file name as asdsd xrs.inp is found on your machine";
$array =explode(" ",$output);
$flag=false;
$filename="";
foreach($array as $check) {
    $place = strpos($check, ".inp");
    if ($place>0) {
        $flag=true;
        $filename=$check;
        break;
    } else {
        $flag=false;
    }
}

if($flag){
    echo '.inp file is running on this server'."<br>";
    echo "File Name:".$filename;
}else{
echo "not present any .inp file"."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Above script for getting a connection through ssh and $stream executes the commands on it., whose result value will taken as input for $output variable.....

Comment: What ever the input string might be, if the file name has no space in it you will get the file name with the above script. I don't know the result of your $stram variable. You may have to check it

Answer (score 0):

You will need a regex like this :

```
$found = preg_match("#([a-z]+)\.inp#", $output, $fileName);
```

And then use `$fileName[1]` if `$found` is true. (`fileName[0]` will contain the whole file name, including extention, whereas `fileName[1]` contains only the file name)

The problem is that your `$checks` array must contain escaped special chars, so it should be :

```
$checks = array('\'.'.inp');
```

So you could use it like this :

```
$found = preg_match("#([a-z]+)".$check."#", $output, $fileName);
```